# Unable to boot with new kernel 6.1.0-9-amd64 after upgraded to Debian 12

Tags: linux, boot, debian, upgrade

I was using LUKS + LVM setup for Debian 11.

After upgraded to Debian 12, when booting with new kernel 6.1.0-9, the screen went black screen with unresponsive idle cursor.

I could boot into LUKS password prompts with old kernel 5.10.0-23.

Error logs (partial) of the failed boot are listed below:

```
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:25:00.0
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: nvme 0000:25:00.0:   device [15b7:501a] error status/mask=00000080/0000e000
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: amdgpu 0000:29:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/dimgrey_cavefish_sos.bin failed with error -2
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: amdgpu 0000:29:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: amdgpu: probe of 0000:29:00.0 failed with error -2
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:25:00.0
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: nvme 0000:25:00.0:   device [15b7:501a] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:25:00.0
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: nvme 0000:25:00.0:   device [15b7:501a] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:25:00.0
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: nvme 0000:25:00.0:   device [15b7:501a] error status/mask=00000080/0000e000
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:25:00.0
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: nvme 0000:25:00.0:   device [15b7:501a] error status/mask=00000080/0000e000
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:25:00.0
Jun 18 08:21:08 republic kernel: nvme 0000:25:00.0:   device [15b7:501a] error status/mask=00000080/0000e000
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. It seems you have several problems. Try to prepare a usb pen with the new System Version (Debian 12), and to boot from that device. If it is all ok it is not an harware compatibility problem. Then (or directly) you can try to boot in a [safe mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode) on your computer and see if it can deal at least with the nvme problems.  Good Luck